# How to remove a line in jsPdf autoTable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a pdf table generated using jsPDF and jspdf-autoTable. I would like to remove the empty line that you can see in the picture. How can I do that?

I would also want to have only one table per page. What do I need to change to get that?

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tabela"));
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: 80}});


var header = function (data) {
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
    if ($scope.distritos[0].entidade.brasao) {
        doc.addImage($scope.distritos[0].entidade.brasao, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 12, 35, 40);
    }
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.text("ESTADO DO " + $scope.distritos[0].uf.nome + "\n" + $scope.distritos[0].entidade.nome, 90, 36);
    doc.text("Total de  " + $scope.distritos.length + " registros ", 455, 50);
};

var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
        top: 80
    },
    startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY()
};

doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one table per page you can try setting the pageBreak option to 'always'.

`doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {pageBreak: 'always'});`

As the author of the autotable plugin, let me know if you have suggestions of how to improve the docs to make this more clear.

The empty line is weird. My guess is that it is something is up with your html.